# Reading multiple text files in different threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I was learning multithreading and wanted to read multiple text files in different threads simultaneously using different threads and get the result in single list. I have text files with First name and Last name of employees.

I have written following Employee class.

```
class Employee {
    String first_name;
    String last_name;
    public Employee(String first_name, String last_name) {
        super();
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }
}
```

Class for reading files, with List to store the objects.

```
class FileReading {
    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    public synchronized void readFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File(fileName));
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] arr = line.split("\\s+");
                employees.add(new Employee(arr[0], arr[1]));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Class with main method and threads.

```
public class TestMultithreading {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final FileReading fr = new FileReading();

        Thread t1 = new Thread() {
            public synchronized void run() {
                fr.readFile("file1.txt");
            }
        };

        Thread t2 = new Thread() {
            public synchronized void run() {
                fr.readFile("file2.txt");
            }
        };

        Thread t3 = new Thread() {
            public synchronized void run() {
                fr.readFile("file3.txt");
            }
        };

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
            t3.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(fr.employees.size());
    }
}
```

Does using join() method ensure to finish the thread on which it was called and proceed to the other? If yes, what is the point of multithreading?
Is there any other way to ensure all threads run parallelly and collect result from them after they all finish in main() method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All threads run in parallel, however your `readFile` method is synchronized, so only one thread can enter it at any time (per object). This is a good choice, since it prevents updating the `ArrayList` (which is not thread-safe) concurrently, but also means that at any time two threads will wait before entering the `readFile` method.

If you create three `FileReading` instances, your code will run in parallel.

The `join()` method performs another kind of synchronization: it blocks the calling thread until the `run()` method of the other thread exits. Hence you are certain that after the three `join`s in your code the three threads have already finished.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer was very elucidative. Refer to it to understand how to solve your problem better. I will give you a recipe along with some explanation as well.

First, you don't need a `FileReading` class (bad abstraction BTW). Just `Runnable` instances (e.g. anonymous classes) which receive the filename to read data from and the destination list.

You pass these Runnables to `Thread` instance constructors and keep them in some list or set, so you can call `thread.start()` on each of them (i.e. with `set.forEach()`) and do the same to `thread.join()`. Nothing needs to be done within synchronized blocks or methods.

This way your main method will wait for all of those threads to finish, while still taking advantage of parallelism (there will be some waiting for slower files to finish but all the threads will still do their heavy work in parallel -- at least as far as the file system/storage allows it).

What you said about `join()` is true, but the possibility of threads to work in parallel before joins is also true. The point is that joins will only happen after each task is concluded. So the file tasks taking less time will all do their work in parallel. Slower tasks still will take advantage of parallelism as a whole while the main method is waiting on the concluded faster ones and next will be the slower ones until all of them have concluded and the main method is finally allowed to go on.

It's like baking a cake, you can do tasks in parallel for a while but all will have to join into a single recipient which goes in the oven in the end.

Second, it is better to create an atomically-insertable `List` (see for instance `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())` or more modern syntax so you can pass it to the Runnables and let them populate it concurrently while still preventing running conditions. This is where synchronized code is needed, and it will already be provided internally in the created list.

Lastly, I don't think you should create one numbered `Thread` reference for each single file, `thread1`, `thread2`, etc. You should have a list of files and create the `Thread`s on demand while traversing it, then storing the `Thread`s in the mentioned set or list for referencing them all at once later as mentioned.

Comment: How to create Runnable instances (e.g. anonymous classes) which receive the filename to read data from and the destination list?

Comment: @Nagaraja Didn't think about that, but if it's not possible to pass it through a constructor, you can initialize public instance variables from the outside as you declare/instantiate the anonymous class. To create an anonymous class instance you do for example `Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { ... } };`

Comment: @NagarajaJB This is why is it's called anonymous, when you use this syntax you are just declaring that you want to instantiate a class that implements the `Runnable` 
 interface and provides an implementation like so-and-so to it, without actually having to declare an usual Java class and give it a name and then calling `new MyClass();`. BTW Java lambdas originally were implemented simply as [syntatic sugar to anonymous classes](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/181743/93338) (it has been a long time since this no longer holds true).